# Mvc Core session timeout even when active

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identity, session-timeout

I have an MVC Core application that will timeout the user even if the user is active.  Even if I am clicking links and loading pages, the session will timeout.

I have a line in the ConfigureServices function of Startup.cs:

```
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
        {
            options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        });
```

This line reduces the timeout to 30 seconds for the purposes of testing, and does have that effect.

In my MVC app all user's are signed in.  If a user is not signed in, a function in the base-controller class OnActionExecuting function will sign-in the user with a guest account, like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{

        // Ioc
        this._signInManager = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SignInManager<ApplicationUser>)) as SignInManager<ApplicationUser>;

        // Get session-state
        _sessionState = _ensureUserSignedIn();

        // Call base-class functon
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

}
```

The sign-in call is this:

```
// Sign-in
var result = this._signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(acc.Username, Program.GuestPassword, true, lockoutOnFailure: false).WaitAndSpit();
```

The session-state is my own class that I store in a RedisCache.  I lookup the session-state with this value:

```
this.User.Identity.Name
```

In the web.config there are no sections for session-state or forms-authentication.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am experiencing the same thing and can't seem to find a solution other than extend SecurityTimeStamp. thank you.